Reply to selected message with template
I want to select template replies, to specific message content, with ribbon buttons.
I created several macros, located in separate modules in the VBA editor.
The macro works in the editor, but not in Outlook.
Sub Odpowiedź_jako_szablon()

    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim replyEmail As MailItem
    Dim oLookMail As MailItem
    Dim oLookItem As Object
    Dim oLookFldr As Folder
    Dim oLookName As NameSpace
    
    Set oLookMail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
    Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\jacek.michalski\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Odpowiedź na reklamację parkingową uszkodzony parkometr.oft")
    
    replyEmail.To = oLookMail.Sender
    replyEmail.CC = oLookMail.CC
    replyEmail.Subject = oLookMail.Subject
    
    replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & oLookMail.Reply.HTMLBody
    replyEmail.Display
    
End Sub

I tried adding a certificate, changing macro security settings, and changing the editor settings to show all errors during the run.

What does "not run" mean? Do you get an error? Is the code executed?

Verify only one instance of  Sub Odpowiedz_jako_szablon() and Module name is not Odpowiedz_jako_szablon.

The line Application.ActiveWindow.Selection assumes that the active window is Explorer. It will break if the current window is an Inspector.
Use TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow) to figure out what the active window is. If it is Inspector, use Application.ActiveWindow.CurrentItem.
